# How do I read XCom of previous message using SimpleHttpsOperator and then decide to execute task 2 in Airflow

Tags: airflow

How do I read XCom of previous message using SimpleHttpsOperator and then decide to execute task 2 in Airflow.

Suppose I have 3 SimpleHttpsOperator task, All the task returns a XCom message, in XCom value it returns success or failure depending on the results.

So before executing t2, I want to check whether t1 was success. 
All my task uses SimpleHttpsOperator

t1 >> t2 >> t3

below is the snippet of my code:

```
t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
                   task_id='t1',
                   http_conn_id='http_temp',
                   endpoint='update_data',
                   method='POST',
                   headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
                   xcom_push=True,
                   log_response=True,
                   dag=dag,
)


t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
                                   task_id='t2',
                                   http_conn_id='http_temp',
                                   endpoint='update_data',
                                   method='POST',
                                   headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
                                   # response_check=lambda response: True if len(response.json()) == 0 else False,
                                   xcom_push=True,
                                   log_response=True,
                                   dag=dag,
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [BranchPythonOperator](http://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=branchpythonoperator#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator). `check_t1_status` & `check_t2_status` in the below chain of dependencies will use `BranchPythonOperator` to check the output of the previous task using xcom. And based on the output, execute the next task or run a dummy tail if the previous task failed.

```
t1 >> check_t1_status >> t2 >> check_t2_status >> t3
check_t1_status >> t1_fail
check_t2_status >> t2_fail
```